# Substrate - Change logging library

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, logging, json

Is there some way to change the logging library or at least the logging format? I need a way of having the logs output in JSON format.

What I tried:
Installed the `tracing-subscriber` pallet with json feature and inside `node/src/main.rs` added the initialization, but it clashes with the built-in logger.
Then I tried disabling it on `sp-api` with feature `disable-logging` but it stills crashes on node start.

Any helpful idea or insight?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the logger with the current code seems to be challenging. However, there is a `create_runner_with_logger_hook` available. Perhaps configuring the log profile could help achieve this.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b7c18f1f5c9dc5c4ffa683e230303f084efe82cb/client/cli/src/lib.rs#L234
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7f0eb5f06e4a403b10be1f7893859dde79f4d813/cli/src/command.rs#L239

Comment: Thanks for the response! As far as I see, that's only for metrics and profiling, don't see a way to configure the log format.